# ContentByQueryWebPart, how to render a user with its presence?

Tags: content-query-web-part

In a custom Xsl file, used in a ContentByQueryWebPart, I would like to display some user fields with the presence indicator.

If I put `<xsl:value-of select="@Author"/>`, I get only the display name of the user.

Is there a simple way to render the user with its presence?

**[edit]** A minimal, reproductible xsl is :

```
<xsl:template name="MyStyle"
            mode="itemstyle"
            match="Row[@Style='MyStyle']">
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Author"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the standard ItemStyle.xsl then there is a reference to CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate.

```
<xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
```

Give this a try?  Or perhaps check out what it does and see if you can reproduce it?

---

Hmmm - looks like this might be legacy from 2007

> If the @SipAddress attribute exists on the current row, it generates
>   the appropriate markup to create a presence icon for Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 or Microsoft Office Communicator 2007

There is a really good walk through how get a presence icon with 2010 on Ben Prin's blog:

http://benprins.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/presence-and-user-profile-url-with-xslt/

Comment: I've seen this template, but I don't know how to link it to my specific user field.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, I miss the SO notification. The link you provided helped me to solve my issue. thanks

Comment: That is great news - well done!